# calculation of distance matrix in a faster approach

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataframe

```
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import pandas as pd
a = {'b':['cat','bat','cat','cat','bat','No Data','bat','No Data']}
df11 = pd.DataFrame(a,index=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8'])
```

and i have a distance function

```
def distancemetric(x):
    list1 = x['b'].tolist()
    result11 =[]
    sortlist11 = [process.extract(ele, list1, limit=11000000, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio) for ele in list1]
    d11 = [dict(element) for element in sortlist11]
    finale11 = [(k, element123[k]) for k in list1 for element123 in d11]
    result11.extend([x[1] for x in finale11])
    final_result11=np.reshape(result11, (len(x.index),len(x.index)))
    return final_result11
```

I call the funtion by

```
values1 = distancemetric(df11)
```

Here the `token_set_ratio` methods compares only two strings. When i pass an array of strings it gives me avg which i dont need.

This code is working but it is slower. Is there any way which could make it run faster